# in R. Break down overall period in monthly sub-periods in a data.frame object

Tags: r, date

I have the following data.frame (just an example with 3 ids):

```
> df
        ID  STARTDATE    ENDDATE
1 qwer.001 2014-01-01 2014-04-01
2 asdf.002 2014-04-01 2014-07-01
3 yxcv.003 2015-01-01 2015-03-01
...


> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID       : Factor w/ 3 levels "asdf.002","qwer.001",..: 2 1 3
 $ STARTDATE: Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-04-01" ...
 $ ENDDATE  : Date, format: "2014-04-01" "2014-07-01" ...
```

`df` (the original version) has about 100k unique IDs, each ID has a START and END date assigned and appears just one time in the data.frame.
I need to transform `df` as follows:

```
> df2 
        ID  STARTDATE    ENDDATE
1 qwer.001 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
2 qwer.001 2014-02-01 2014-03-01
3 qwer.001 2014-03-01 2014-04-01
4 asdf.002 2014-04-01 2014-05-01
5 asdf.002 2014-05-01 2014-06-01
6 asdf.002 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
7 yxcv.003 2015-01-01 2015-02-01
8 yxcv.003 2015-02-01 2015-03-01
```

The overall period of each ID is broken down into monthly sub-periods.
Any hint or idea on how I could solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution using function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. It uses original `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE` to make sequence of dates and with `tail()` or `head(`) selects last or first values.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(ID),function(x)
      data.frame(STARTDATE=head(seq(x$STARTDATE,x$ENDDATE,by="month"),-1),
      ENDDATE=tail(seq(x$STARTDATE,x$ENDDATE,by="month"),-1)))
        ID  STARTDATE    ENDDATE
1 asdf.002 2014-04-01 2014-05-01
2 asdf.002 2014-05-01 2014-06-01
3 asdf.002 2014-06-01 2014-07-01
4 qwer.001 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
5 qwer.001 2014-02-01 2014-03-01
6 qwer.001 2014-03-01 2014-04-01
7 yxcv.003 2015-01-01 2015-02-01
8 yxcv.003 2015-02-01 2015-03-01
```

As your data frame is large then you could look also on the library `data.table` for faster solution.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(df)
dt[,list(STARTDATE=head(seq(STARTDATE,ENDDATE,by="month"),-1),
   ENDDATE=tail(seq(STARTDATE,ENDDATE,by="month"),-1))
   ,by="ID"]
```

Comment: Hi, I am impressed. This is what I was looking for. Thanks for that.